# Using Ansible playbook to create instances in google cloud (gcp)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

I'm using the following code

```
- name: create a instance
  gcp_compute_instance:
    name: test_object
    machine_type: n1-standard-1
    disks:
    - auto_delete: 'false'
      boot: 'true'
      source: "{{ disk }}"
    metadata:
      startup-script-url:
      cost-center:
    labels:
      environment: production                                                               
    network_interfaces:                                                                     
    - network: "{{ network }}"                                                              
      access_configs:                                                                       
      - name: External NAT                                                                  
        nat_ip: "{{ address }}"                                                             
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT                                                                
    zone: us-central1-a                                                                     
    project: test-12y38912634812648                                                         
    auth_kind: serviceaccount                                                               
    service_account_file: "~/programming/gcloud/test-1283891264812-8h3981f3.json"      
    state: present
```

and I saved the file as create2.yml

Then I run Ansible-playbook create2.yml and I get the following error

```
ERROR! 'gcp_compute_instance' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/Users/xxx/programming/gcloud-test/create2.yml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: create a instance
  ^ here
```

I followed the documentation. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't created a playbook, you've just created a file with a task which won't run on it's own as you've discovered.

A playbook is a collection of tasks. You should start with the playbook documentation:

[Playbook Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html)

For GCP, here's a working example to create a network, external IP, disk and VM.

```
- name: 'Deploy gcp vm'
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: false
  gather_facts: no

  vars: 
    gcp_project: "671245944514"
    gcp_cred_kind: "serviceaccount"
    gcp_cred_file: "/tmp/test-project.json"
    gcp_region: "us-central1"
    gcp_zone: "us-central1-a"


  # Roles & Tasks
  tasks:

  - name: create a disk
    gcp_compute_disk:
      name: disk-instance
      size_gb: 50
      source_image: projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/family/ubuntu-2004-lts
      zone: "{{ gcp_zone }}"
      project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
      auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
      service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
      state: present
    register: disk

  - name: create a network
    gcp_compute_network:
      name: network-instance
      project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
      auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
      service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
      state: present
    register: network

  - name: create a address
    gcp_compute_address:
      name: address-instance
      region: "{{ gcp_region }}"
      project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
      auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
      service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
      state: present
    register: address

  - name: create a instance
    gcp_compute_instance:
      name: vm-instance
      project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
      zone: "{{ gcp_zone }}"
      machine_type: n1-standard-1
      disks:
      - auto_delete: 'true'
        boot: 'true'
        source: "{{ disk }}"
      labels:
        environment: testing
      network_interfaces:
      - network: "{{ network }}"
        access_configs:
        - name: External NAT
          nat_ip: "{{ address }}"
          type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
      auth_kind: serviceaccount
      service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
      state: present
```